# Fastboot: error: Failed to boot into userspace fastboot; one or more components might be unbootable

Tags: android, pixel, fastboot

I encountered a problem when I was using fastboot to brush Google Pixel 4a. I remember that I executed fastboot flash fastbootd xxxxx. Now my phone cannot use the official system. Only the fastboot mode page can be displayed.

```
PS D:\sunfish-sq3a.220705.003.a1-factory-c1963f71\sunfish-sq3a.220705.003.a1-factory-c1963f71\sunfish-sq3a.220705.003.a1> .\flash-all.bat
Sending 'bootloader_a' (8369 KB)                   OKAY [  0.309s]
Writing 'bootloader_a'                             (bootloader) Flashing Pack version s5-0.4-8351029
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 0
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 1
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 2
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 4
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 5
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_config_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition aop_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition tz_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition hyp_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition abl_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition keymaster_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition cmnlib_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition cmnlib64_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition devcfg_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition qupfw_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition uefisecapp_a
(bootloader) Flashing partition logfs
OKAY [  0.236s]
Finished. Total time: 0.808s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.049s]
Finished. Total time: 0.051s
Sending 'radio_a' (72372 KB)                       OKAY [  1.719s]
Writing 'radio_a'                                  (bootloader) Flashing Pack version SSD:g7150-00090-220406-B-8411773
(bootloader) Flashing partition modem_a
OKAY [  0.342s]
Finished. Total time: 2.525s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.048s]
Finished. Total time: 0.051s
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: s5-0.4-8351029
Baseband Version.....: g7150-00090-220406-B-8411773
Serial Number........: 0B021JEC214512
--------------------------------------------
extracting android-info.txt (0 MB) to RAM...
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.070s]
Checking 'version-bootloader'                      OKAY [  0.068s]
Checking 'version-baseband'                        OKAY [  0.068s]
Setting current slot to 'a'                        OKAY [  0.082s]
extracting boot.img (64 MB) to disk... took 0.184s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
Sending 'boot_a' (65536 KB)                        OKAY [  1.549s]
Writing 'boot_a'                                   OKAY [  0.232s]
extracting dtbo.img (8 MB) to disk... took 0.017s
archive does not contain 'dtbo.sig'
Sending 'dtbo_a' (8192 KB)                         OKAY [  0.299s]
Writing 'dtbo_a'                                   OKAY [  0.093s]
archive does not contain 'dt.img'
archive does not contain 'recovery.img'
extracting vbmeta.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.000s
archive does not contain 'vbmeta.sig'
Sending 'vbmeta_a' (8 KB)                          OKAY [  0.138s]
Writing 'vbmeta_a'                                 OKAY [  0.077s]
extracting vbmeta_system.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.000s
archive does not contain 'vbmeta_system.sig'
Sending 'vbmeta_system_a' (4 KB)                   OKAY [  0.140s]
Writing 'vbmeta_system_a'                          OKAY [  0.075s]
archive does not contain 'vendor_boot.img'
extracting super_empty.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.001s
Rebooting into fastboot                            OKAY [  0.069s]
< waiting for any device >
fastboot: error: Failed to boot into userspace fastboot; one or more components might be unbootable.
Press any key to exit...
```

I hope my phone can be restored, at least it can be brushed into the official system.